# REST из коробки в Yii2 а также его сортировка и связи

Tags: yii2, rest

В идеальном вакууме REST выглядит привлекательно. Но как с ним работать в реальной жизни. На первый взгляд всё радужно

```
модель    GET controller/id
список    GET controller
создать   POST controller
обновить  PUT controller/id
удалить   DELETE controller/id
```

эти actions для ActiveController лежат в /vendor/yii2/rest. Но как с ними взаимодействовать в случае сортировок и связей? Если я хочу жадно вытянуть релейшены для списка или указать в нём сортировку. Только вариант с перепопределением экшенов?

Comment: С сортировкой, вопрос отпал. Нужно было обновится до версии 2.0.13, в которой добавили dataFilter
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rest/IndexAction.php
Хотя от примера реализации не отказался бы. Ну и жадной загрузкой открыт пока что

Answer (score 0):

Только переопределять экшены как вы написали выше.

ActiveController сделан именно как готовая прослойка между базой и приложением, которая возвращает данные "как есть".